# Не загружаются видео youtube в chrome

Tags: веб-программирование, google-chrome, youtube

Подскажите с чем может быть связано:

Сам youtube загружается корректно, видны все области - комменты, похожие видео, даже превью в баре навигации видны, но видео не загружаются. В консоли при этом следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что выдает IExplorer

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуй для начала отключить `adbock` и прочие блокировщики

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не помогает, ту какая то проблема с сертификатами безопасности. В IExplorer явно вылезает окно с предложением не посещать сайт и предупреждение что сертификат googlevideo.com истек. Мне кажется с этим проблема, но хз что это значит

Comment: Решилась проблема - сбилась системная дата, при исправлении все заработало, может пригодится кому